# How to serve static nextjs pages with express

Tags: express, next.js, deployment

I want to deploy my monorepo app to Render and I have a bit of a challenge serving static exported nextjs app from express api. Previously the frontend client was built using only react and I was serving the FE app easiliy like this

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development") {
  app.get("*", function (request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../client/build", "index.html"));
  });
}
```

Now nextjs exports multiple files for each route `index.html, resource/[id].html ...etc`, how can I build my next app and route it through the express app?

Alternatively how can I deploy my frontend app for free? I've tried without any luck to deploy
on vercel/render/aws ec2 but couldn't for similar reasons (aws ec2 lacks http support without a bought domain). The whole repository was previously deployed on heroku, but there's no longer a free tier on there.

Comment: You can deploy both next.js app and express app on render.com for free. This is my favorite option that I've been utilizing.
Or, you may use Vercel for the next.js app, and Render for the express.js app.